# Angular universal not adding scripts

Tags: angular, universal

**I cant add angular universal to my project, i need it for prerendering**

Every tutorial i see online when ppl use ng add @nguniversal/express-engine, they all get some package.json scripts updated.

`When i do the same i add the angular universal, but nothing changes in package.json, and i cant prerender my project routes. When i try to add again, i see error that angular universal is already installed`

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of your `package.json` file (`dependencies` & `devDependencies`)?

Answer (score 0):

instead of **ng add @nguniversal/express-engine**

use:

**ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [nameOfProject]**